# What's wrong with numpy? I can't see result

Tags: numpy, math

```
import numpy as np
import math
print -1/2*np.log2(1/2)-1/2*np.log2(1/2)
```

prints `nan`

Can you explain?

Comment: Yep: `RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in log2. RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars`

Comment: Try replacing `1/2` with `.5`: `-.5*np.log2(.5)-.5*np.log2(.5)` -> `1.0`

Answer (score 0):

change python version as well
The first is python 2.7, the second is python 3.5

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> print(-1/2*np.log2(1/2)-1/2*np.log2(1/2))
nan
>>> print(-1/2*np.log2(1/2)-1/2*np.log2(1/2))
1.0
```

More information requested...

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> print(-1/2*np.log2(1/2)-1/2*np.log2(1/2))
__main__:1: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in log2
__main__:1: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
nan
```

Now this can be avoided by floating your terms... the easiest ways is to do it directly...

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> print(-1/2.*np.log2(1/2.)-1/2.*np.log2(1/2.))
1.0
```

Same numpy version, just python has changed between 2.7 and 3.5

Comment: Without more information added to this answer, it's kind of worthless.

Answer (score 0):

In python 2.x division between ints is euclidean division, so 1/2 is 0, and np.log(0) returns nan.

Using python 3:

```
Python 3.5.2 |Anaconda 4.2.0 (64-bit)| (default, Jul  2 2016, 17:53:06) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)] on linux
>>> 1/2
0.5
```

whereas in python 2:

```
Python 2.7.12 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, Jul  2 2016, 17:42:40) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)] on linux2
>>> 1/2
0
>>> 1./2
0.5
>>> from __future__ import division
>>> 1/2
0.5
```

I have included two ways to get ordinary division in python 2: using a float (1. instead of 1) or importing division from __future __